# Session object with WCF?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to use Session object with WCF to store session related data?
If yes the can you describe how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the Instance mode to PerSession. And then your object that implements the OperationContract becomes the session object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Per Session Instance Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx#S2).